# Strange state in input at the amplifier

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, schmitt-trigger

I have this schematic, an invert Schmitt trigger attached to the RC component to create a triangle wave. 
It's an oscillator. 
The two oscillators go in to the amplifier, but I don't understand why I need another capacitor and 2 resistors ( the red part ).

Someone can help me? 
[image: stage]

Comment: In each of those blocks, one of the resistors is a potentiometer. The other is there to set the minimum resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two (sort-of) triangular waveforms are AC-coupled to eliminate the ~Vdd/2 bias and prevent excessive loading of the signal. The 100K resistor and 500K pot adjust the attenuation, then the signals are combined via the diodes.

The 100K is probably to keep the oscillators from stopping entirely or behaving in a squirrely manner when the input impedance of the amplifier is low.

Comment: thx you, but I have a question about the 100k resistor in serial with 500k potentiometer. When the potentiometer go to zero, the minimal resistor still at 100k. Why?

Comment: "The 100K is probably to keep the oscillators ..."